# Which azure service plan is best for hosting an SPA with high traffic

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-webapps

SPA in Angular 8 needs hosting on the Azure web app. which will be the best plan Basic, Standard or Premium? or can we go with the Azure Storage approach?

Answer (score 1):

App service plan in Azure is essentially the set of compute resources for your application to run, and each every app service plan tier offers some features.

As you have mentioned that this is going to be your production build and incoming traffic to the app would be higher - The Standard app service plan should be fine for you which is recommended for production workloads. As far as the tier is concerned - you can start with S1 and monitor the traffic or load or even perform the stress testing to conclude the right capacity. Going with standard plan will not only offer you the SLA of 99.95% but will also enable you to configure additional and quite useful features such as auto-scaling, custom domain, SSL and daily backups.

Do note that - App Service Free and Shared (preview) hosting plans are base tiers that run on the same Azure virtual machines as other App Service apps. Some apps might belong to other customers. These tiers are intended to be used only for development and testing purposes. So you can still use cost effective plans but ensure that you are using free or shared app service plans only for your development and test environments.

Comment: Thanks, Bhushan for your information. Even I was also thinking about the S1 plan to start with then will see the performance. In addition to this, how will you see if a logic app with a request trigger receives more than 1000 hits at once? Will there be any performance issues or failure chances?

Comment: Logic app being the serverless offering of Azure, scale and concurrency should not be an issue, however as per the logic app limits documentation trigger concurrency is Unlimited when the concurrency control is turned off. For additional details, you can refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#concurrency-looping-and-debatching-limits

Answer (score 1):

The best way to host Single Page Application is by the usage of Storage Account. Besides the huge cost saving, you can easily integrate it with CDN to fast the deliver of the assets to your end users.

Useful links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2018/08/08/angularwithazurestorage/

Comment: I implemented this approach and it worked perfectly, is this recommended for production apps as well or this is the best-case scenario for DEV/TEST/QA? Will this be able to manage high stress/load?